# Looping a Dice-Roll Simulation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been assigned an example as part of my homework in which a red and a blue die are rolled, and their totals summed, as per the below code calling on both the NumPy and pandas libraries:

```
red = np.repeat(np.arange(1,7),6)
blue = np.tile(np.arange(1,7),6)
dice_roll = pd.DataFrame({'Red':(red),'Blue':(blue),'Total':red+blue})
```

We're told that choosing at random from 'Total' is the equivalent to a single roll of both dice, which appears to hold true, but the exercise hinges on making multiple rolls of these dice.

From here, how would I simulate rolling the dice a specified number of times? I've a feeling that implementing a loop would be my best bet, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it...

Comment: where is the randomness?

Comment: A basic example that might help: `import random` then `random.randint(a, b)` will generate a random integer between `a` and `b` (inclusive). If it is a 6-sided die, you could use `random.randint(1,6)` to simulate a dice roll.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of the values of each roll

```
import random


def roll_dice(number):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(number)]


def main():
    print(roll_dice(20))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Obviously this doesnt use numpy or pandas. But it performs the same function. This key part is the roll_dice function.